# Mass payouts suggestion for third party

Tags: paypal, payment

Let's say I have a software that does accounting for businesses. These businesses collect money that, at the end of the month, they need to forward to their clients.

Meaning, at the end of the month, my software produces an accounting statement that goes like this

- Send x € to Client A
- Send y € to Client B
- and so on

Today, the businesses then manually log into their bank account and type in every transaction.
But now, I'd like to automate that process by suggesting the businesses a "bulk transaction" on e.g. PayPal. At the end of the month, they log in and see a "Pay with Paypal" button. Once they click, they get taken to Paypal and the bulk transaction my software has created is shown to them. They can decline or accept it.

Once they've gone ahead and sent out the transaction, my software gets notified if the transaction was successful or not.

A few more things to consider:

- My software is operated from Germany. Here, as soon as my software can "touch" the money of the businesses I'm serving, I'll have to get permission from BaFin. So I'd like to not have access to any money of the businesses I'm serving!
- I want to make the process as smooth as possible from a UX perspective.

I've looked at the PayPal API. I've found that Mass Pay is deprecated. And so is Adaptive Payments... So the only option left would be the Payouts API. But I can't find a way where I can suggest the businesses a transaction but then get notified later if it was successful...
I could have them upload a csv. But then how do I know if it was paid?

Ideally, I could:

- Generate a csv of all the recipients + amounts
- Business downloads it from my software and uploads it to their Paypal. They confirm.
- Somehow there's a webhook that calls my software to tell it whether the transaction succeeded.

I've also looked at the Reports API. In that case, I'd ask the businesses that I'm serving to allow me to access their reports and would periodically download them. But that neither seems to work as the Adaptive Payments API is deprecated.

Any ideas on how to solve this on PayPal? Any other providers I could take a look at?

Answer (score 0):

Require all clients to be [approved](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/prerequisites/#get-access-to-paypal-payouts) for PayPal Payouts and provide you with a ClientID and Secret to facilitate payments via the [Payouts API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/api-integration/#create-payout). You can be notified via the Payouts API batch details.

If checking batch details isn't enough, you can implement [webhooks](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/#event-type-support) for updates.